# Single occurrence of a value in a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a column I have some values, some of which only occur once, others occur multiple times. I want to identify the values that only occur once, and then count the number of those values depending on them having a specific value in an adjacent column i.e.

```
Col A............Col B   
John.............8              
John.............2   
Phil.............1   
Bill.............4   
Dick.............1    
Dick.............2
```

For example, I want to find the values in column A that appear only once (i.e. Phil and Bill), and for those values, I want to identify the ones that have a value of 4 in column B

In this case, the answer to my question is 1 there is only one instance of a value in Col A that is a single occurrence, and which has a value of 4 in Col B

I want to be able to do this in Google Sheets!

Comment: Welcome. That sounds like a challenging problem. How far have you got with developing a solution?

Comment: Hahaha - tried Query, Count functions, Unique functions - I'm not that strong a Sheets user, but I'm beginning to think that what I want to do isn't actually possible :(

Comment: Yes, I tried those myself but I _do_ think query is probably the answer - personally, I'm not good with query but others will be much more willing to help if they can see _that_ you have tried AND _what_ you have tried AND the outcome(s) you got. FWIW, I don't think the title properly describes your problem. Seems to me that the issue is something like: "Single occurrence in column PLUS specific value in adjacent column". For example `=QUERY(QUERY(B2:C7,"SELECT B, COUNT(B) GROUP BY B ORDER BY COUNT(B) DESC"),"WHERE Col2 = 1 LABEL Col2 ''")` but then how to evaluate for ColumnC=4?

Comment: BTW, it is better to supply a sample spreadsheet but (FWIW) if one copies the sample data into a spreadsheet `=split(A1,".",True,True)` will resolve it to two columns of clean data.

Comment: Would you please clarify what represents a successful answer? Is it the name(s) of the people (mentioned once and with a value of 4), or a count of the names of the people...? Based on your sample data, is the answer "Bill" or "1"?

Comment: I actually wanted both pieces of information and so I've put a count () round the query and that gives me the count. My question wasn't clear in respect of whether I wanted the count, or the items to be identified. Either piece of info would have done when I asked the question because I didn't have much hope of getting a solution.

Comment: Is it at all possible that no-one will have a value of 4? Is so, then there's an `iferror` (or equivalent that needs to be added somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(VLOOKUP(QUERY(QUERY({A2:B},
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  group by Col1"),
 "select Col1 
  where Col2=1"), A2:B, {1,2}, 0),
 "where Col2=4"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: mate, that's superb, i've copied your screenshot onto my computer, put in the formula and it works 100%

Comment: Thank you - what I want to do in real life is a little bit more complex than in my example, but now you've shown how to do it, I can apply the principles to what I want to do in real life - amazing, didn't think it could be done, thanks again

Comment: @player0 What is the benefit/purpose of finishing off with `arrayformula`?

Comment: @Tedinoz it's for vlookup if there would be more unique holders for value 4 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/shrUx.png

Comment: Question asked for information only: I've transposed ARRAYFORMULA and the final QUERY so the syntax now reads like this *** =query(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(QUERY(QUERY({A2:B}, "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1"), "select Col1 where Col2=1"), A2:B, {1,2}, 0)),"where Col2=1" ) ***, Is there any disadvantage with doing the enquiry this way round? It seems to produce the same results. [fyi, I've been working out how the syntax worked and it seemed more logical to me, possibly, that it should be written this way round [asking for info' only, just trying to educate myself]

Comment: @roger it doesn't matter where the array formula is located (in the middle or in front). also pls accept the answer and upvote if this answer solved your question

Comment: This is the first question I've ever asked on Stackoverflow - I've your answer as having answered the question - do I need to do anything else in order to 'uvote' it?